# Android unit test/test.runner - access to Application object

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-context

I'm using the android.test.runner library and the AndroidTestCase etc. to create some unit tests. I'm finding it useful, but one test requires access to the application object. Usually I just get that from the activity context, e.g.

```
AppState appState = ((AppState) myActivity.getApplicationContext());
```

However, the unit tests are in a class which extends AndroidTextCase, and as far as I can see there is no getApplicationContext available. There is a getContext, but I'm not clear if that's what I want. What's the best course of action?

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing your AppState object, or trying to test something else which relies on it?
If you are not testing AppState in this instance can you use a tool such as Mockito to mock up an AppState object for the purposes of your test.

Comment: Would I do something like: 1) add mokito's jar into the project 2) import something mockito int my unit test 3) code something like "AppState appState = mock(AppState.class)

Comment: Add the mockito jar into your test project, I prefer to do a static import of: import static org.mockito.Matchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*; Then, yes, AppState appState = mock(AppState.class). You can then do neat stuff like when(appState.getSomething.thenReturn("something"); to fake up test data

Comment: I saw after I typed in my comment :)

Comment: If that's useful I'll put it in the answer text, rather than a comment

Comment: scrap that - found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522312/best-practices-for-unit-testing-android-apps which suggests you can't use Mockito, it has other useful suggestions though

Comment: Wow, I wish I had seen that earlier. It didn't show up till I went to add a comment that Mockito doesn't work with android.